# C# Trying to filter by date in RowFilter (Reporting)

Tags: c#, .net, filter, datatable, reporting

Im trying to filter by the dates picked in two datetimepickers.
When I debug the program it exits with the code "Access Violation"

```
filter = "date > #"+desde_dateTimePicker.ToShortDateString()+"# AND date < #"+hasta_dateTimePicker.Value.ToShortDateString()+"#";

this.DataTable1TableAdapter.Fill(this.DataSet1.DataTable1);
this.DataSet1.DataTable1.DefaultView.RowFilter = filter;
DataTable1BindingSource.DataSource = this.DataSet1.DataTable1.DefaultView;
this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

If I write manually the dates in the filter string, it works.

Comment: Show the stracktrace of the exception, is it really raised at the line `this.DataSet1.DataTable1.DefaultView.RowFilter = filter;`?

Comment: No, its something related to the date conversion to string. But the weird thing is that if I write the dates manually instead of taking them from the datetimepickers it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to here you need to have your dates formatted in a specific way.

http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/

```
dataView.RowFilter = "Date = #12/31/2008#"          // date value (time is 00:00:00) 
dataView.RowFilter = "Date = #2008-12-31#"          // also this format is supported 
dataView.RowFilter = "Date = #12/31/2008 16:44:58#" // date and time value

dataView.RowFilter = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat,
                     "Date = #{0}#", new DateTime(2008, 12, 31, 16, 44, 58));
```

When you use the .ToString methods then this relies on your regional settings which may not be correct.

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much! I replaced it with: `filter = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat, "date > #{0}# AND date < #{1}# ", desde_dateTimePicker.Value, hasta_dateTimePicker.Value);`